Use Confluent Kafka .NET AdminClient to Retrieve Topic Read / Write Permissions
I need to implement a programmatic check to view read / write permissions to a Kafka topic.
I'm attempting to use the AdminClient, but I'm getting back 0 ACLs.
    using (var adminClient = new AdminClientBuilder(kafkaConfig).Build())
        {
            var filter = new AclBindingFilter
            {
                PatternFilter = new ResourcePatternFilter
                    { Type = ResourceType.Any, Name = null, ResourcePatternType =     ResourcePatternType.Any },
                EntryFilter = new AccessControlEntryFilter()
                    { Principal = null, Host = null, Operation = AclOperation.Any, PermissionType = AclPermissionType.Any }
            };

            try
            {
                return await adminClient.DescribeAclsAsync(filter);
            }
            catch (DescribeAclsException ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"An error occured {ex.Result.Error}");
                throw;
            }

    }

What am I doing wrong?
Tried above, expecting a list of topics with permissions
